# Chrome Extension: screenshot is taken before layout changes are applied

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The following function in my content script should get a page screenshot from the background script:

```
var takeScreenshotFn = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
            {
                command: "takeSingleScreenshot"
            },
            function (response) {
                resolve(response.screenshot);
            }
        );
    });
};
```

The background script has a listener that is processing the message:

```
if (message.command === "takeSingleScreenshot") {
    // Coming in from the content script, returns response to content script.
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function (screenshotUrl) {
        sendResponse({
            success: true,
            screenshot: screenshotUrl
        });
    });
}
return true;
```

Now, in the content script, I try to automate highlighting certain DOM nodes and taking screenshots:

```
promise = promise.then(function () {
    var j;
    ...
    for (j = 0; j < leafs.length; j++) {
        leaf = leafs[j];
        leaf.oldBGColor = leaf.style.backgroundColor;
        leaf.style.backgroundColor = "#fc0";
        leaf.style.setProperty("background-color", "#fc0", "important");
    }
    if(leaf) console.log(window.getComputedStyle(leaf).getPropertyValue('background-color'));
    return takeScreenshotFn().then(function (highlightedShot) {
        for (j = 0; j < leafs.length; j++) {
            leaf = leafs[j];
            leaf.style.backgroundColor = leaf.oldBGColor;
            delete leaf.oldBGColor;
        }
        if(leaf) console.log(window.getComputedStyle(leaf).getPropertyValue('background-color'));
        ...
    });
```

If I take screenshots using that code, the issue is that some of the screenshots are taken before the highlighting is visible in the screenshot. Which of the nodes are affected differs between the runs, it seems completely random. Using a different `takeScreenshotFn` based on [`html2canvas`](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), the highlighting works correctly and deterministically, but the screenshots are of course not as good (due to known `html2canvas` limitations) and it takes 20 times as long:

```
var takeScreenshotFn = function () {
    return html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
        return canvas.toDataURL();
    });
};
```

Is this a known problem and/or is there some function I can call to make sure the browser processes the layout changes before taking the screenshot?

Comment: @wOxxOm I highlight first, then call takeScreenshotFn, and in the `then` block the original background color is restored.

Comment: Ah. I see. Then try sending the message in a requestAnimationFrame() callback.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just tried but it doesn't help. I found that `setTimeout` with 50ms seems resolves the issue on my machine, but of course an event or a callback would be the more robust solution.

Comment: Assuming you've invoked it correctly, that sounds like a bug now because a rAF callback runs when the page is actually painted. Try forcing a repaint by accessing offsetHeight of some `leaf`.